# What do I have to change to allow a local XP computer to open the event log on a remote windows 7 Computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, event-log

I want to open the event log of a Windows 7 SP1 computer remotely from a Windows XP SP3 computer.

Both computers are on a domain, and the user has domain admin privilages.  The firewall is turned off of both computers.

I can connect to the Windows 7 computer with some MMC applets, ie I can remotely connect to the Windows 7 services, and "computer management" allows me to connect to the Windows 7 computer.

When I use XP event viewer to try and connect to the Windows 7 computer it tells me "The Network path is not found".  When I use "Computer Management" I can connect to the Windows 7 computer, I can view remote shares under that, local users, local groups, sessions, open files.  when I click on "Event Viewer" the error "The Network path is not found" is displayed.

The XP computer can connect to the event log on a windows 2008 r2 server, and the Windows 2008 r2 server can connect to the Windows 7 event log.

I'm at a loss of what else to try.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are all the appropriate services on the target machine running? ie remote management, remote registry, etc? Also, have you tried managing it from ANOTHER XP machine, because you should be able to remote manage, I do it all the time here with XP to Win 7 and vice a versa.

Comment: It seems it was the remote registry service, it is disabled by default, once I'd started that up the event viewer is working correctly.  (I had to enable it to get sophos anti virus installed, but if you want to put an answer in I will mark it as the answer)

Comment: Excellent, I'll get one posted up right away. Yeah we use Sophos too, one of the things that got me enabling and disabling those services as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are all the appropriate services on the target machine running? IE remote management, remote registry, etc? You should be able to remote manage, I do it all the time here with XP to Win 7 and vice a versa.

Comment: It was specifically the "remote registry service".

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
wevtutil <command> /r:<remote_computer_name> /u:<user_name> /p:<password>
```

Comment: No, as it seems wevtutil is only a Windows Vista+ tool, and I'm using XP.